# Create Function inside ajax

Tags: javascript

**Hello,**
I would like to create a function that is used within the ajax action several times, both to validate and invalidate. This facilitates the execution process and the number of lines.

I don't know if I'm right, as I'm using the same actions a lot in several ajax calls, I wanted to customize using a function, like this:

```
function alertMessage(id_css,messages){ var id_css;

var messages;

  $(id_css).fadeTo(5000,500).slideUp(500, function() {
      $(id_css).html(messages);
      $(id_css).slideUp(500);
  }); 
}
```

How should I call the function that is outside the ajax's inside? Like this...

```
  // AJAX - Insert
  $(document).on("submit", '#formInsertUser', function(ev) {
    // Valores
    var dados = {
      buttonAcess: $('#insertUser').val(),
      first_name : $('#first_name').val(),
      last_name : $('#last_name').val(),
    }

    var modal_title = $("#modal-title");
    var modal_body_info = $("#modal-body-info");
    var modal_footer_button = $('#modal-footer-button');

    $.ajax({
      url : "php_action/collaborators.php",
      type : "POST",
      data : dados, 
      async : true,
      cache : false,
      dataType : 'html',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        table.ajax.reload();      
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);   
        if(obj.success){
          $('#progress-insert').html('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning" style="width:40%;" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"> 40% </div>');

          $("#nav-user-complement-tab").removeClass("disabled").tab("show"); 

         **HERE CODE FUNCTION**
         alert = new alertMessage("#valid","Sucess");

        } else{
          $("#invalid-user").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500);
          $("#invalid-user").html(obj.messages);
          $("#invalid-user").slideUp(10000);
          document.getElementById("formInsertUser").reset();
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        $("#invalid-user").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500);
        $("#invalid-user").html("Deslogue e acesse o Sistema novamente");
        $("#invalid-user").slideUp(10000);
        document.getElementById("formInsertUser").reset();
      }    
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
  // AJAX - Insert - End
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call it as usual: `alertMessage("#valid","Sucess")`

But remove those vars definitions from function body, because they overwriting provided arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define new variables in the function body without the same name.

```
// AJAX - Insert
$(document).on('submit', '#formInsertUser', function (ev) {
  // Valores
  var dados = {
    buttonAcess: $('#insertUser').val(),
    first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
    last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
  }

  var modal_title = $('#modal-title')
  var modal_body_info = $('#modal-body-info')
  var modal_footer_button = $('#modal-footer-button')

  function alertMessage(id_css, messages, fadeToTime, slideUpTime) { //your function
    $(id_css)
      .fadeTo(fadeToTime, 500)
      .slideUp(500, function () {
        $(id_css).html(messages)
        $(id_css).slideUp(slideUpTime)
      })
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'php_action/collaborators.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dados,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      table.ajax.reload()
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data)
      if (obj.success) {
        $('#progress-insert').html(
          '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning" style="width:40%;" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"> 40% </div>'
        )

        $('#nav-user-complement-tab').removeClass('disabled').tab('show')

        alertMessage('#valid', 'Sucess', 5000, 500) //1st call
      } else {
        alertMessage('#invalid-user', obj.messages, 2000, 10000) //2nd call
        document.getElementById('formInsertUser').reset()
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.error(error)
      alertMessage('#invalid-user', 'Deslogue e acesse o Sistema novamente', 2000, 10000) //3rd call
      document.getElementById('formInsertUser').reset()
    },
  })
  ev.preventDefault()
})
// AJAX - Insert - End
```